# How to install a FORTRAN compiler on macOS?

Tags: osx, software-installation, sudo, fortran, brew

I am trying to install a Fortran compiler on my Mac Pro 2019 (running macOS).  First step is:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

but I get error: `command not found`

I also tried

```
brew install gfortran
```

also

```
port install gfortran
```

but again, the same error.

Comment: First, `apt-get` is for Debian/Ubuntu/Mint and derivatives and not MacOS. To use `brew` or `port`, you'll need to install them as they are third-party tools and don't come with MacOS. The instructions for installing `brew` are here: https://brew.sh/ and the instructions for installing `port` are here: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to install gfortran you should try gcc instead. gcc install comes with gfortran. This is available from homebrew or MacPorts.

Another method is to install pre-compiled binaries from [here](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases). Select the version based on your Mac OS version and you get an apple style loader. A .dmg file ready to load on your mac.